# How do I get my custom jQuery modules to work after upgrading to Kentico 8.1?

Tags: jquery, conflict, kentico

After upgrading to Kentico 8.1, my site's jQuery modules seemingly disappeared.  Kentico is unilaterally injecting its own jQuery module, overwriting my own reference.  How do I prevent this?

Answer (score 3):

This topic is covered in the following article: [Using a custom jQuery when developing pages in Kentico](http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/using-a-custom-jquery-when-developing-pages-in-kentico).

Kentico currently creates a jQuery alias. What you need to do is open the jquery-core.js file and locate the line stating:

```
var $cmsj = jQuery.noConflict();
```

Comment this line and then uncomment the line:

```
var $cmsj = jQuery.noConflict(true);
```

Comment: Link-only answers are deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Kentico's own site documents the problem [here](http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/using-a-custom-jquery-when-developing-pages-in-kentico).  The solution is to customize Kentico's built-in jquery-core.js file, replacing the line `var $cmsj = jQuery.noConflict();` with the line `var $cmsj = jQuery.noConflict(true);`.  And pray that subsequent hotfixes/upgrades don't revert this change.